# when ammonium nitrate dissolved in water, is not it against thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, ionization-energy

I want to understand what is actually happening in this endothermic reaction. I have read the explanations, that for ionization of NH4 and NO3 it requires energy and it is absorbed from the surroundings. But why it is happening against thermodynamics.

If dissolving ammonium nitrate into water requires energy than it should not dissolved until the energy is applied. So what is there in action, by what force the energy is being absorbed from surroundings?

Comment: Recall that the Gibbs Free Energy has both enthalpy and entropy components.

Comment: It is not against thermodynamics.  There are also chemical driving forces that are driving the reaction.

Comment: @ChetMiller can you elaborate a bit more, what are these chemical driving forces ?

Comment: The chemical potentials of the products are lower than the chemical potentials of the reactants initially.